# Page Views, Click Counts for Users in a microsite

Tags: view, count, click

I am working on web app, where users that have registered account with my website will have a custom page that they can share with their network.

I am currently researching on providing a feature which will give registered users the ability to monitor Page views count, click count, and click ratio of for their custom page.
However all my search with existing tools and solutions is not giving me a satisfactory approach. Would love to know if anyone knows how to crack it!

I have checked on Google free analytics, but could not figure out how it can show unique clicks/page views to every user who will log into their own pages.